# No column name was specified for column 1 of 'tbl'

Tags: sql-server

When am executing the below query in sql server 208 r2
I am getting error message No column name was specified for column 1 of 'tbl'.

```
SELECT rollno, 
       classid, 
       t_class.classname 
FROM   t_class 
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT Count(classname), 
                        classname 
                 FROM   t_class 
                 GROUP  BY groupname 
                 HAVING Count(classname) > 1)tbl 
              ON tbl.classname = t_class.classname
```

Comment: `Count(classname)` is column 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using your subquery in JOIN, your column needs to have a name:

```
SELECT rollno, 
       classid, 
       t_class.classname 
FROM   t_class 
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT Count(classname) as CountOfClasses, 
                        classname 
                 FROM   t_class 
                 GROUP  BY groupname 
                 HAVING Count(classname) > 1)tbl 
              ON tbl.classname = t_class.classname
```

But since you are not using this aggregate field in your query, you can actually remove it at all:

```
SELECT rollno, 
       classid, 
       t_class.classname 
FROM   t_class 
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT classname 
                 FROM   t_class 
                 GROUP  BY groupname 
                 HAVING Count(classname) > 1)tbl 
              ON tbl.classname = t_class.classname
```

Comment: @Neminath hey, if this answer works for you then accept answer and upvote it, so it can be helpful to other and other people come to know it as a perfect answer!! Thanks!