# How to find out the count from union query ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want to find out the row's count from an `UNION` query.

I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID)
   FROM [Laola].[AGG_0] 
   GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
   UNION
   SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) 
   FROM [Laola].[AGG_2] 
   GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
) x
```

I received follow error:

> No column was specified for column 3 of `x`

Comment: This is one of many SO posts addressing the `No column was specified for column # of x` They all have different sources but essentially the answers/solutions  are all the same. Inner query was missing column name. See this possible duplicate of [**No column name was specified for column 1 of 'tbl'**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000895/no-column-name-was-specified-for-column-1-of-tbl) as one example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a name to column where COUNT calculation is being applied.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) Count
   FROM [Laola].[AGG_0] 
   GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
   UNION
   SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) 
   FROM [Laola].[AGG_2] 
   GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
) x
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the 3rd column an alias:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) As Count
   FROM [Laola].[AGG_0] 
   GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
   UNION
   SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) As Count
   FROM [Laola].[AGG_2] 
   GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
) x
```

Comment: You don't need an alias for the count in the second subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Technically, no, you are correct.  But It's just a personal habit to always alias both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You just need an alias for the column:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
       SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) as nr
       FROM [Laola].[AGG_0] 
       GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
       UNION
       SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) 
       FROM [Laola].[AGG_2] 
       GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
    ) x
```

Comment: You don't need an alias for the count in the second subquery.

Comment: Haha! Yes sure, just out of habit. Edited!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do a `UNION` query!  It removes duplicates. Use `UNION ALL`.

The following gives a row count and the sum of the unique counts from each table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(cnt)
FROM ((SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) as cnt
       FROM [Laola].[AGG_0] 
       GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT Platform, DeviceCategory, COUNT(DISTINCT FullVisitorID) as cnt
       FROM [Laola].[AGG_2] 
       GROUP BY Platform, DeviceCategory
      )
     ) x;
```

If you are not using the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, then remove it from the subqueries.  It incurs overhead, and I'm not 100% sure the optimizer will remove it.

From the perspective of accuracy, conciseness, and efficiency, I would recommend:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT Platform, DeviceCategory
       FROM [Laola].[AGG_0] 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT DISTINCT Platform, DeviceCategory
       FROM [Laola].[AGG_2] 
      )
     ) x;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used `UNION` query in order to check if two `result` sets are equal.After I used `UNION`, if I get the `count` greater than any of two tables, that means that they don't have same data. That's the reason I used `UNION`.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai . . . That is a mis-use of `UNION`.  You should be using  something like `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead.  Perhaps you should ask another question on the best way to accomplish your goal.  And, if yours is the downvote, I consider it rude in this case.

Comment: It seems that the @downvoter removes the `downvote`.